# Что такое Interactor

Tags: android, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучаю архитектурные паттерны и никак не могу понять что такое interactor и что в него выносить? Как его применять совместно с mvp?

Comment: [Хабропост](https://habrahabr.ru/post/273061/)

Comment: @AGS17 Спасибо, я прочитал пост. Но а что касательно interactor-a в mvp? В mvp вся бизнес логика в презентере. Я правильно понимаю, что если презентере становится слишком большим, то его можно разбить на интеракторы?

Comment: в посте четко описано цели интеракторов - они служат для абстракции всей логики конкретной модели данных и определяют интерфейсы для работы на бизнес слое

Comment: @Garic Почитай описание MVP. `Модель (англ. Model) — хранит в себе всю бизнес-логику, при необходимости получает данные из хранилища.`

Answer (score 10):

Если по простому:

Вы можете думать об интеракторе как о «модели / контроллере». Интерактор будет извлекать данные из вашей базы данных, веб-служб или любого другого источника данных (`Repository`). После получения данных интерактор отправит данные в `Presenter`.

Преимущества использования интерактора в отдельном классе заключаются в том, что он отделяет ваш класс, делая его более чистым и тестируемым. Конечно, вы можете поместить логику интерактора в класс презентатора, но в чем смысл?

Надеюсь мой ответ помог вам.

Comment: Timur Mukhortov, скажите пожалуйста, выходит интерактор это Фасад? Т.е. тот класс, который часто именуется DataManager и он объединяет в себе интерфейсы Helper'ов ?   Видел такую вот логику: презентер знает про DateManager, а менеджер имплементирует интерфейсы Базы данных, Сетевой интерфейс и так далее.

Comment: @Turalllb, не совсем. Смысл фасада скрыть большую сложность какого-то модуля за простым интерфейсом. Допустим у вас есть либа по шифрованию данных, для ее работы нужно создавать кучу сложных сущностей, устанавливать связи между ними и т.п. Да, сложный интерфейс предоставляет большую гибкость, но и усилий на изучение требует много. Поэтому делают фасад - простой интерфейс а-ля "зашифруй мне эту строку", который под капотом реализует всю сложную магию. Как в автомобиле - под капотом трындец что происходит, но пользователь видит только руль и педали).

Comment: @Sneg нельзя писать, что фасад "шифрует эти строчки", хороший пример с капотом, тип спрячь то что мне не нужно знать.  Все сами эти слои сделаны с целью того чтоб не знать что там под капотом и то что я писал в ответе выше..

Comment: @Turalllb  мое мнение, интерактор также скрывает работу с хранилищами и все сводится к обращению через интерфейс.. поэтому и может можно считать что он выполняет роль фасада, но четко сказать он это или нет.. Я не берусь.